# Is there such a thing as a throttling valve that can operate with oil as the working fluid?

Tags: pcv-valve, throttle-position-sensor

I'm searching for a throttling valve that uses oil in order to convert pressure into thermal energy that can then be extracted via a cooler. Is there such a thing as a oil throttling valve? It would also need to handle fairly large pressures (1000 - 3000 psi). The whole idea is to dissipate approximately 400 kW of power during the most extreme situation. Does anyone know of a better way to convert kinetic energy (spinning shaft) into thermal energy for extraction? Btw this is a fairly large vehicle (about the size of a dump truck)

Thanks,
Digimas

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to give more information about the application to attract answers.

For example, define "dissipate": do you mean to scrub off enough thermal energy to bring temps to within 2 degrees of ambient? 20? 200?

Is the goal to use this intermittently or for constant use? Big difference in BTU's there.

And is your goal to bring the shaft to 0 rpm or simply to apply a load of up to 400kW to a shaft powered at a much higher level?  Do you have a time constraint for reaching desired shaft speed? How much hysteresis is allowable? etc.

Hope this helps...